# How can I get the maximum value of a richtextbox's vertical scrollbar?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, scrollbar

I need to get the maximum value of a richtextbox's vertical scrollbar so that I can scroll to a percentage of the scrollbar's maximum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've done it, I have the RichTextBox inside of a ScrollViewer, e.g.

```
<ScrollViewer Name="sv">
  <RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
      <Paragraph />
    </FlowDocument>
  </RichTextBox>
</ScrollView>
```

Then from code-behind, you can read the value of sv.ExtentHeight, take a percentage of it, and then call sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset() to move the scrollbar to that position.